# What is the limit of the field type BIGINT in SQL?

Tags: sql, bigint

What is the limit of the field type BIGINT in SQL?

is 100000235882380 or 100000466411115 acceptable? (That is ID  from facebook)

Comment: I guess for portability, you may want to use a string instead.  In my case I encoded the twos-complement value (BigInteger.toBytes) using Base64 and looked up by that when accessing the database.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check the manual of the RDBMS you're using. It may not be the same in all systems.

MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

PostgreSQL:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-numeric.html

SQL Server (Transact-SQL):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql

DB2:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_biginteger.htm

Comment: Are there any other RDMSs that have a BIGINT type other than SQL Server? Maybe a similar type but I think it is fair to conclude that OP is using SQL Server.

Comment: MySQL, Postgres... there are more users of RDBMS's with BIGINT *other than* SQL Server than users of SQL Server.

Comment: Actually, if bigint is defined in the ISO SQL standard as 64 bits (which I suspect it is), then you wouldn't need to make an exhaustive list of databases, only the ones too brain-damaged to conform to the standard.

Comment: @Jeff: Unfortunately, SQL standard says only this about the ranges of integer types: "The precision of SMALLINT shall be less than or equal to the precision of INTEGER, and the precision of BIGINT shall be greater than or equal to the
precision of INTEGER." (a precision is the number of bits of the integer type)

Comment: This old DB2 link is dead; DB2's numeric data types can now be found at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dtl-numbers

Answer (score 10):

Yes, according to [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx):

> **bigint** `-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)`

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the RDBMS. For example, the maxiumum values of a BIGINT are `9223372036854775807` (for signed) or `18446744073709551615` (for un-signed) on MySQL.

See the [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) section of the docs for the full details.

Comment: Note that this is for MySQL, other database platforms may or may not have the same limits (alas, the OP didn't specify which SQL db was meant).

Comment: @Piskvor - Good call, a presumption too far on my part. I'll update my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about. BIGINT can store much larger values than the ones you have.

At a minimum up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.